# .htaccess RewriteRule to Custom URI

Tags: .htaccess

I have a GET form and the variables passed into the URL are rewritten with .htaccess to for a custom URI for an app to open. My problem is the domain is still passed with the rewrite in front of the URI.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?form=selection&numbers=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) customURI:selection%1  [R,NC,L]
```

This turns into http://domain.com/customURI:selection"numbers" instead of just customURI:selection"numbers".

Comment: What are you using as `customURI` in your rule, a relative or absolute path and with or without the full qualified domain?

Comment: I would like the domain stripped from the result so it is just "customURI:blueorange100011". Then my app would recognize it. Think of it as similar to mailto: then your email client opens.

The rewrite is creating it but it is also putting the domain in front of it and I dont want that.

Comment: An http URL will always have a domain name, you can't remove it, and if you do, the browser will give you an error

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is not an answer but still a solution.

I turned to JS to take on submit and push to a URL.

```
<script>
function process()
{
var url="customURI:" + document.getElementById("var1").value + document.getElementById("var2").value;
location.href=url;
return false;
}
</script>

<form onSubmit="return process();"> 
Selection<select id="va1" name="var1">
<option value="blah0">Blah 0</option>
<option value="blah1">Blah 1</option>
<option value="blah2">Blah 2</option></select>
Numbers<input id="var2" type="text" size="12" name="numbers"> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```